# How to format timestamp in outgoing JSON

Tags: json, time, formatting, go

I've been playing with Go recently and it's awesome. The thing I can't seem to figure out (after looking through documentation and blog posts) is how to get the `time.Time` type to format into whatever format I'd like when it's encoded by `json.NewEncoder.Encode`

Here's a minimal Code example:

```
package main

type Document struct {
    Name        string
    Content     string
    Stamp       time.Time
    Author      string
}

func sendResponse(data interface{}, w http.ResponseWriter, r * http.Request){
     _, err := json.Marshal(data)
    j := json.NewEncoder(w)
    if err == nil {
        encodedErr := j.Encode(data)
        if encodedErr != nil{
            //code snipped
        }
    }else{
       //code snipped
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/document", control.HandleDocuments)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:4000", nil)
}

func HandleDocuments(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    switch r.Method {
        case "GET": 
            //logic snipped
            testDoc := model.Document{"Meeting Notes", "These are some notes", time.Now(), "Bacon"}    
            sendResponse(testDoc, w,r)
            }
        case "POST":
        case "PUT":
        case "DELETE":
        default:
            //snipped
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to send a request and get the Stamp field back as something like `May 15, 2014` and not `2014-05-16T08:28:06.801064-04:00`

But I'm not really sure how, I know I can add `json:stamp` to the Document type declaration  to get the field to be encoded with the name stamp instead of Stamp, but I don't know what those types of things are called, so I'm not even sure what to google for to find out if there is some type of formatting option in that as well.

Does anyone have a link to the an example or good documentation page on the subject of those type mark ups (or whatever they're called) or on how I can tell the JSON encoder to handle `time.Time` fields?

Just for reference, I have looked at these pages: [here](http://pauladamsmith.com/blog/2011/05/go_time.html) and [here](https://gobyexample.com/json) and of course, [at the official docs](http://golang.org/pkg/json/)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

What you can do is, wrap time.Time as your own custom type, and make it implement the `Marshaler` interface:

```
type Marshaler interface {
    MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
}
```

So what you'd do is something like:

```
type JSONTime time.Time

func (t JSONTime)MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    //do your serializing here
    stamp := fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", time.Time(t).Format("Mon Jan _2"))
    return []byte(stamp), nil
}
```

and make document:

```
type Document struct {
    Name        string
    Content     string
    Stamp       JSONTime
    Author      string
}
```

and have your intialization look like:

```
 testDoc := model.Document{"Meeting Notes", "These are some notes", JSONTime(time.Now()), "Bacon"}
```

And that's about it. If you want unmarshaling, there is the `Unmarshaler` interface too.

Comment: This though does not allow to use all the other functions in the `time` package, like `After` and `Before`.

Comment: @DejoriDavid you just gotta cast it back to `time.Time` to do that: `time.Time(myJsonTime).After(...`

Answer (score 79):

Perhaps another way will be interesting for someone. I wanted to avoid using alias type for Time.

```
type Document struct {
    Name    string
    Content string
    Stamp   time.Time
    Author  string
}

func (d *Document) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Alias Document
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        *Alias
        Stamp string `json:"stamp"`
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(d),
        Stamp: d.Stamp.Format("Mon Jan _2"),
    })
}
```

Source: http://choly.ca/post/go-json-marshalling/

Comment: I found this to be the cleaner and more contained option. However, I opted to use `Document` rather than `*Document` as the receiver because this custom `MarshalJSON` function was not being called on individual document objects (in a detail api view), but was when the api responded with a slice of documents (really pointers to those documents). Something to look out for. (this article was helpful for me: https://hackernoon.com/today-i-learned-beware-with-pointer-in-golang-7764f2060a93)

Comment: This is great, but how could I `Unmarshal` this again?

Comment: @kramer65 by implementing JSON Unmarshaler interface, i.e. give it a `UnmarshalJSON` method.

Answer (score 50):

I would NOT use:

```
type JSONTime time.Time
```

I would use it only for primitives (string, int, ...). In case of `time.Time` which is a struct, I would need to cast it every time I want to use any `time.Time` method.

I would do this instead (embedding):

```
type JSONTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t JSONTime)MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    //do your serializing here
    stamp := fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", t.Format("Mon Jan _2"))
    return []byte(stamp), nil
}
```

No need to cast `t` to time. The only difference is that new instance is NOT created by `JSONTime(time.Now())` but by `JSONTime{time.Now()}`

Comment: Great recommendation. By the way, if you are wondering how you can convert it back to a `time.Time`, you simply need `t.Time`, where `t` is a `JSONTime`: https://golangbyexample.com/anonymous-fields-struct-golang/

Answer (score 9):

> But I'm not really sure how, I know I can add json:stamp to the Document type declaration to get the field to be encoded with the name stamp instead of Stamp, but I don't know what those types of things are called, so I'm not even sure what to google for to find out if there is some type of formatting option in that as well.

You mean [tags](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Tag). But these won't help you with your formatting problem.

The string representation you get for your time is returned by [`MarshalJSON`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) implemented by [`Time`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.MarshalJSON).

You can go ahead and implement your own `MarshalJSON` method by copying the relevant bits from the [`Time` implementation](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/time/time.go?name=go1.2.2#935) by either embedding `time.Time` or wrapping it. Wrapping example ([Click to play](http://play.golang.org/p/PcuFaT4gHn)):

```
type ShortDateFormattedTime time.Time

func (s ShortDateFormattedTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    t := time.Time(s)
    if y := t.Year(); y < 0 || y >= 10000 {
        return nil, errors.New("Time.MarshalJSON: year outside of range [0,9999]")
    }

    return []byte(t.Format(`"Jan 02, 2006"`)), nil
}
```

Comment: upvote for the great links. the other answer was just a bit faster. Your naming convention for the date is better though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above answers, here is a bigger example that includes unmarshalling.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type (
    JSONTimeMs struct {
        time.Time
    }

    JSONTimeUs struct {
        time.Time
    }
)

func (ms JSONTimeMs) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    str := fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, ms.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"))
    return []byte(str), nil
}

func (ms *JSONTimeMs) UnmarshalJSON(text []byte) error {
    if len(text) < 26 {
        return errors.New("malformed millisecond timestamp")
    }
    str := string(text[1:25])
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z", str)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ms.Time = t
    return nil
}

func (us JSONTimeUs) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    str := fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, us.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000Z"))
    return []byte(str), nil
}

func (us *JSONTimeUs) UnmarshalJSON(text []byte) error {
    if len(text) < 29 {
        return errors.New("malformed microsecond timestamp")
    }
    str := string(text[1:28])
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000Z", str)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    us.Time = t
    return nil
}
```

Also after unmarshalling, you probably want to work with the inner `Time`, e.g., `myjsontime.Time`.