# Data type for storing date time offset in golang

Tags: json, postgresql, datetime, go

I am using go language to develop an application. In my program I receive a JSON data which contains an entity in date time offset format for example **DateTime": "2014-10-19T23:08:24Z"**

I need to unmarshal the JSON and store it in the database in the **TIMESTAMP(p) WITH TIME ZONE** format in PostgreSQL database. When I unmarshal, I need to store this in a variable of the same data type.

Is there a data type available in Golang to do this or any other means of doing this?

Comment: Is the problem in unmarshaling the time, or in storing it in postgres (what client?)

Comment: Is this the direction you need? this answer is about converting times to json, but the principal is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695479/format-timestamp-in-outgoing-json-in-golang

Comment: *Note* that PostgreSQL does not actually *store* the time zone offset in that field/type. Instead, it will be taken into account, when input/output occurs (inputs normalized to UTC ((-ish, actually to UT1)) and outputs `timestamptz` values according to the current set [`TimeZone` setting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html)).

Answer (score 2):

The `time.Time` struct is aware of the timezone, and should be properly handled by most of the SQL drivers available.

The only thing to add is that the convention in most systems is to use only UTC dates in exchange formats (JSON, SQL, etc) and let the application shift to timezone when necessary.