# Mutating a string on Unmarshal

Tags: go

I have a `Profile{}` struct with an `ID` property of the type `uuid.UUID`. When I marshal this, I am converting the `UUID` to a `string`, like this:

```
type Profile struct {
    Id      uuid.UUID
}

func (profile *Profile) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Alias Profile
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Id string
        *Alias
    }{
        Id:    profile.Id.String(),
        Alias: (*Alias)(profile),
    })
}
```

However, when I want to unmarshal this JSON, it complains that the `id` is a string. So I need to initialise a `UUID` struct when unmarshalling, like this: `uuid.New([]byte(jsonId))`

Is this possible to do without altering the `UUID` implementation, and if so, how?

Comment: You can create your own marshalable/unmarshalable  UUID type by wrapping the UUID, as seen in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695479/format-timestamp-in-outgoing-json-in-golang

Comment: Which package are you using? If [this one](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-uuid/uuid) then it already implements `json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest storing `Id` as string instead of `uuid.UUID`. Of course there are workarounds, but if you're not going to hold thousands of `Profile`s in memory, you shouldn't notice any difference, and you'd be saving time dealing with serialization issues.

If you don't want that, check out the `uuid` package you're using. Is the underlying type of `UUID` really a string? If it's something else, like `[]byte`, just convert your string to `[]byte` before unmarshaling.

The idiomatic workaround would be what Not_a_Golfer commented under your question.